# imagerotate returns false every time

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to rotate an image using php. I cannot seem to get the 'imagerotate' function to work.  This is my code:

```
<?php
$degree = 45;

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("mike.jpeg");

if($img == false){
echo 'imagecreatefromjpeg fail <br />';
}else{
echo 'imagecreatefromjpeg success <br />';
echo 'value $img: '.$img.'<br />'; //'Resource id #3' given.
}


$imgRotated = imagerotate($img, $degree, -1);// This is the problem!

if($imgRotated == false){
echo 'imgRotate fail <br />';
echo 'imgRotate value: '.$imgRotated.'<br />'; // '0' is returned every time
}else{
echo 'imgRotate success <br />';
}


 imagejpeg($imgRotated, 'mikeRotated.jpeg', 100); // ERROR: 'imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given'
 ?>
 <img src="mike.jpeg"/>
 <img src="mikeRotated.jpeg"/>
```

This is my gd_info():

GD Version / bundled (2.1.0 compatible) 
FreeType Support / 1 
FreeType Linkage / with freetype 
T1Lib Support / 1 
GIF Read Support / 1 
GIF Create Support / 1 
JPEG Support / 1 
PNG Support / 1 
WBMP Support / 1 
XPM Support / 1 
XBM Support / 1 
JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support /

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the bottom line is i cannot rotate the image. so the code above was an attempt to find out where the problem lay. So the error i am getting is that quoted above in the code (see ERROR message)

Comment: I'm just testing your code - should be able to give you an answer in a minute or two :D

Comment: Is minus one a valid value as third argument? Seems to me it's only valid as transparency information in PNG files.

Answer (score 3):

Faced with this problem. All one to one. It turned out that it is impossible to send imagerotate batskground of **-1** (rotating jpg-file). Put to **0**, worked. 
The quality problems because of the choice of colors are not seen.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code, the only problem I found was that you wrote `<img src="mikeRotated.jpg"/>`, rather than `mikeRotated.jpeg`, which is the name of your picture.

Refer to the screenshot below, using your exact code (except for the above change):

[image: screenshot 1]

Not too sure why your code won't work. Could you provide a link to the image you are using?

Edit: used your image as well. Still not sure what's wrong... are you sure you've included the GD library inside `php.ini`? [Refer to this link to check](http://www.zoopable.com/check-php-gd-library-installed-or-not/)

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: i've made the edit that you pointed out and my code still does not work. as for the link for the image, i;ve tried numerous images and no success.  the present one that i am using:https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQh3Eft1g0res-vqeHGMQZholp6tyRizK5ebCco3am4nuX4jxBIrQ

Comment: @dave still not sure what's wrong on your side - do other image operations under GD work for you?

Comment: 'imagecreatefromjpeg' appears to work. this is based on the assumption that what i got returned is correct when the function is success (please see above). I have only just started attempting to work with the gd library. please see above edit for the gd_info().

Comment: @dave Can you try the script I linked in my answer?

Comment: ive tried the script in the link and gd does appear to have been installed.  i have detailed the gd_info() above.